# Pepper not respoding to Dialog

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I am using Naoqi's dialogs and using multiple topics. I checked with

```
ALDialog.getAllLoadedTopics and ALDialog.getActivatedTopics
```

They both show that my topics are loaded and activated. But Pepper doesn't respond to most of the activated topics. When I enter the same text on the Dialog input on Choregraphe, pepper replies correctly but not using voice commands.

Comment: Then it seems to be a recognition problem. In what language did you write the topics? Is the robot currently configured in the same language? Also did you try in a quiet environment? (NAO/Pepper tend to have difficulties to understand in a noisy place)

Comment: Hi Eino, I am using English

Comment: Could you copy the snippet of the topic causing issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Speech Recognition is in a weird state ? this has happened to me before during development, and issuing a "nao restart" to reload naoqi does solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue is it doesn't respond even after restart. But when I put the same keyword via choregraphe it responds.

Answer (score 0):

For me mostly is happening when I switched between two languages in another package. To avoid add `set language` and `speech recognition language` to your target language. It should work.